# What does processing_rate in AppEngine MapReduce mean?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce

Following is from the documentation in the source code:
mapreduce\handlers.py(570): processing_rate: How many items to process per second overall.

Does this limit the total number of input elements that are provided to all the mappers combined in one second?

Answer (score 0):

It should be.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/overview?hl=zh-tw

> Processing rate limiting to slow down your mapper functions and space
>   out the work, helping you avoid exceeding your resource quotas